C# program cannot find C++/CLI DLL
Steps done:

Standard C# program was made (actually, it's
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).
That works.
A C++/CLR .NET class library was made (I need to keep
some code 'invisible' from the users of the executable, not possible
with C#, IP-reasons...).
I want to call a static method from the C++
class.
I made sure both C#/C++ use the same .NET version
(see answer here Managed C++ namespace not accesible in C#.Net during compilation)
The C++ is correctly (I assume) referenced by the C# module, else
compilation would already fail.

When I start the C# program, I get the following error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException HResult=0x80070002 Message=Could not load file or assembly 'grpc_server_processing, Version=1.0.8900.14343, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source> StackTrace: <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
The C++ DLL is where it should be, I also tried copying the DLL to the same folder as the C# executable, same error. Starting C# executable outside Visual Studio: same error. The version number of the DLL in the error message is the same as I see in Visual Studio in the object browser:

I have no idea what could be wrong, any help is very welcome.

is it compiled as x86 or x64?  both ur c# and c++ project should match

Does the c++ part of the mixed dll has additional dependencies that are missing? The exception name might be missleading here. The message is better here "Could not load file" and normally closer to the problem. Could not load errors are often about missing dependencies of that dll not about the dll itself.

Did you add a reference from grpc_server to grpc_server_processing ? That should take care of most dependencies. If there are native dependencies involved you could use dependency walker to find anything missing. Or remove all dependencies (and related code) from your c++/cli project to eliminate that possibility.

@Alander: there are 3 or 4 tabs or windows with properties that give conflicting information for both projects C#/C++. Some say x64, some say Any CPU, and where settings seem to conflict I cannot give them the same settings. Absolutely confusing.... But would that actually give a 'file not found' error?

@Ralf: the error states the missing file explicitly, including the name. There are no additional dependencies from there, the C++ class is as good as empty with only one test-method (one line...) to get the framework working.

@Ralf: you're right! There's an MS dll ljwhost.dll in the C++ build folder: I cannot reference it, but if I copy it besides the c# executable, things work...

"But would that actually give a 'file not found' error?" No. Conflicting bitness would typically end in a BadImageFormatException. Same error message but different type.

A self-answer for quick reference, thanks to @Ralf in the comments to fill in my blind spot.
It turns out that the C# executable needs the MS ijwhost.dll to load the C++/CLR library. That DLL must be copied into the same folder as the C# executable, then things work.
